# How can I get Jasmine-jQuery to correctly read z-index properties?

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, jasmine

I'm using [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) and [Jasmine-jQuery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) to test the Javascript in my application. I set up an HTML fixture have successfully tested showing and hiding elements and other interactions, but so far, I can't get it to correctly set and read a z-index value.

Here's a failing test:

```
    it("understands z-index values", function(){
      loadFixtures('input_tips.html');
      $('span.tip:first').css('z-index',200);
      expect($('span.tip:first').css('z-index')).toEqual(200);
    });
```

This test fails; the z-index is read as "auto."

So far I've tried:

- Setting and checking other CSS attributes, like color, in my test. This works fine.
- Setting and checking z-index values with jQuery in my console. This works fine.
- Setting the z-index as a string value instead of a number. Makes no difference.
- Hard-coding the z-index in an HTML "style" tag. Makes no difference.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because z-index only makes sense when position attribute is present and set to 'relative' or 'absolute'. Please try changing it to:

```
it("understands z-index values", function(){
  loadFixtures('input_tips.html');
  $('span.tip:first').css({'position':'relative','z-index':200});
  expect($('span.tip:first').css('z-index')).toEqual('200');
});
```